# Why is my counter incrementing in loop, but returns zero?

Tags: java, counter, class-variables

With my current project, I have to keep a counter of the number of insertions into a `TreeMap<String, TreeSet<Song>>`.  The project is to run search of individual words in a string, in this case, song lyrics.  I have three tests to determine the course of the map insertions, and my algorithm goes:

- test if word has more than one character and is not a common word
- if map already contains the word as a key, test if set already contains the song
- if true, increment insertion counter
- if map doesn't contain word as key
  - make new node, add song to set
  - increment counter

I declare the counter as `private double insertions;` as a class variable.

It is initialized in the constructor:

```
public SearchByLyricsWords(SongCollection sc) {
    this.songs= sc.getAllSongs();
    buildSongMap();
    insertions=0;
    totalReferences=0;
    averageReferences=0;
}
```

The buildMap method:

```
for (String word:currentLyrics) {
    if (word.length()>1 && !commonWords.contains(word)) {
        if (lyricWords.containsKey(word)) {
            if (!lyricWords.get(word).contains(song))
                insertions++; //this is a non-duplicate song in the set
            lyricWords.get(word).add(song);

        } else {
            TreeSet<Song> songSet= new TreeSet<Song>();
            songSet.add(song);
            lyricWords.put(word, songSet);
            keyWords.add(word);
            insertions++;
        }
        //System.out.println(word+" added");
    }
} //end loop through string
```

Why is a class variable that is modified in a method, not then giving the correct value in another method?

Comment: Why do you reset the counters after building the song map?

Comment: not that it will fix your problem, but why is `insertions` declared as a `double`? surely this should be an integer...

Comment: because at the start of this project, I had no idea how many words there would be added to the map.  The project has us read in 10500+ songs with complete lyrics.  I did not know if the total insertions would be greater than the capacity of an integer, so thus the `double`

Comment: long - 
8 bytes signed (two's complement). Ranges from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807.  Comparisons involving doubles are non trivial, use an integral type for your counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
public SearchByLyricsWords(SongCollection sc) {
    this.songs= sc.getAllSongs();
    insertions=0;
    totalReferences=0;
    averageReferences=0;
    buildSongMap();
}
```

Comment: Declaring the counter as a double seems odd too, as pointed out by Mark E

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are setting the variable to zero right after calling the buildsongmap function.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been mentioned, it's a matter of initialization in the constructor.  One other thing:  in your buildSongMap method, you are adding the song to the map regardless of whether or not it already contains it.  Although you're using a Set, which will prevent duplicates, I think it's more readable to only perform the add in the case where it already does not exist.

```
if (!lyricWords.get(word).contains(song)) {
  insertions++;
  lyricWords.get(word).add(song);
}
```